# jQuery event handle breaking

Tags: jquery

I am trying to dynamically generate embed html code as a user types in some information in an adjacent text box. The problem I am having is that the $add_link_box handle seems to break inside the "on" event handler, and does not change the value of my $add_link_box text field.

```
$add_link_box = $("<input>", {type: "text", class: "code_div_text_field"});
$link_text_box = $("<input>", {type: "text", class: "link_text_box"});
$code_div.append($link_text_box);
$code_div.append($add_link_box);

$link_text_box.on('change keyup paste',function(event) {
   $add_link_box.val($(this).val());
});
```

If I instead use:

```
$('.code_div_text_field').val($(this).val());
```

then the text box populates correctly. The obvious answer seems to be that element handles don't persist into asynchronous callbacks, however I've been using this same syntax all over my program's code with 'div' elements without any problem. Is there any difference in how jQuery handles 'input' vs. 'div' elements that would explain this inconsistency?

(I also had $link_text_box.val() instead of $(this).val() originally but changed it due to what I gather is the same problem).

Comment: `$add_link_box` wouldn't stop pointing to the correct element, is this the exact structure of the code in the real app? it works for me http://jsfiddle.net/Wwn3g/

Comment: Hmm, yeah the link you included worked for me too! The code you see is more or less the same  removed some other irrelevant text fields that get initialized and appended to make it easier to read. I should probably come back and look at it with a pair of fresh eyes because I thought this code was proper as well, so maybe I am overlooking a blatant typo.

Comment: You're likely missing some scope issue. The `on` events are being called in a scope in which `$add_link_box` doesn't mean anything.

Comment: you need to show more context to the code in question... whether the elements are created in a loop etc... try adding `var $add_link_box` to make the variables local in scope

Comment: You guys were correct! Adding "var" in front of the definitions fixed my problem. I usually do that not sure how I missed it; fatigue I guess. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem may be the order of two inputs, as your code supplied:

```
$code_div.append($link_text_box);
$code_div.append($add_link_box);
```

that the first is link_text_box element actually has binded event.